# Assigning public key to user's login

Tags: authentication, centos6, ssh-keys, public-key

I have a Centos 6.4 server and I need to assign certificate to user's login so that he doesn't need to enter password during login. The user has already provided the id_rsa.pub -file. I don't have his credentials and I'm working with the root account

The was no .ssh directory under his home folder so I created one, but I don't know how to advance from here..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

so, as root you need to create a $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys with the right owner and permissions. Something like this should work

```
cd /home/theuser
mkdir .ssh
cp /some/path/id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys
chown theuser .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 . .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys
```

the permission may not have to be so tight but if it's to loose ssh won't allow the key to be used and complain about it in some syslog.